# What is the purpose of putting Class after your variable like this ($_.Class)?

Tags: powershell, class

What is the purpose of this string? I am still new to PowerShell and have seen this come up quiet a bit.

```
$_.Class
```

Here is an example of how I have seen it used:

```
$R.AllElements|?{$_.Class -eq "table"}|select innerText
```

Does this meant that we are applying a class on the $R variable? Or is there a "Class" already for that variable that we are searching for the string "table"? I have looked around but cannot find any explanation.

Comment: that is referring to  a property of the object - in this case an HTML `class`. it comes from parsing the HTML into an object with something like `Get-Web-Request`. it is NOT a _class_ in the classic programming meaning ... it's just an HTML structure name. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for you to understand the purpose of `$_.xxxxx`

```
$Obj = Get-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files'
```

This would put any information gathered by the `Get-Item` command and store it in `$Obj`. If you then show what's in the variable, it will look something like this

[image: Example]

If you would then do `$obj.xxx` where xxx is one of the property names shown above, it will show you the values under that property like this

[image: Example part 2]

Another way to get the values of said properties is how you have shown in your post. If you *pipe* the variable into a where statement like below, it is especially helpful when trying to filter out some text inside a particular variable. This example is looking for the text `prog` in the `Name` property of all the items inside of `$Obj2`

[image: Example part 3]

I wish I had time to give more details, I hope this helps you some! PowerShell is one of the best tools for Automation and Administration in a Windows environment so keep on learnin!

Bonus: [Here is a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6) to documentation on PowerShell's pipelines and how it works, I referred to it as 'pipe' in my wordage above